# Bluetooth receiver combining differential outputs to single ended (LR, N) to one (main) secondary amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio, bluetooth

I recently purchased a CSR8645 Bluetooth Module

[image]

I have a Sony MHC GX Music system  with AUX/MD Video Audio input (Left Right Ground).

But in my CSR8645

```
SPK L P1
SPK L N1

SPK R P1
SPK R N1
```

How to combine these to power the music system?

Connected LP1, RP1, battery - to music system, but getting low volumes; also tried connecting both LN1+RN1 to ground input to music system, but getting a lot of distortion.

TPA6120A2

[image]

powered with battery

very high distortion

Answer (score 1):

A little understanding may help.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEIJqt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Left: the intended operation. Right: modification for your use.*

Since the module doesn't have a ground connection for the speakers that means that it is working in bridge mode. There are two amplifier outputs per channel and each channel's outputs are 180° out of phase. (This is represented by the gain of +1 and -1 respectively in Figure 1.) Bridge mode allows us to double the voltage seen by the speaker and for a given speaker impedance we can also double the current with the result that up to four times the power is possible on the same supply voltage.

When the bridge mode amplifier is in quiescent state the two outputs will be at half the supply voltage. With a grounded loudspeaker this would result in a DC current through the coil biasing the cone in one direction and producing continuous heat so this is avoided by adding a DC blocking capacitor in series with the speaker. With the bridge mode the same DC voltage is applied to both sides of the speaker so they cancel out. Since there is no DC current there is no need for the capacitor and a better bass response is obtained.

For your use you should try to configure as shown in Figure 1 right. Leave L_N1 disconnected, add a DC blocking capacitor to L_P1 and connect the grounds.

You may find that you have too high a signal level from this setup and a 10:1 or 100:1 voltage divider may be required on the output.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this module is designed to work with speakers. Speakers do not need a common ground. That has the advantage of being able to use a [Bridged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridged_and_paralleled_amplifiers) type output for steering the speakers which can produce more output power and lowers component cost.

Such an output is really only suitable for driving speakers. What you need is an output with a common ground which is suited to drive headphones. You can connect such a headphone output to your music system without issue.

There are also CSR8645 based modules that have a **headphone** output. It is unclear to me if it is possible to convert your module to a headphone output type. It could be that the CSR8645 chips only needs a different setting and maybe a few extra components.

Since there modules aren't that expensive, I would just get the headphone output type and use that.